# Had an exterior front door installed

Tags: doors, door-frame

The gap between the latch area and striker is too wide. Makes it easy to shim the latch if someone wanted to.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: A picture would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, a picture, please, that shows the consistency of the gap all around the door. And an actual measure of how wide the gap is.

Comment: Note that the latch-to-striker gap is irrelevant to the shimming/jimmying attack surface of a proper latch; as long as the deadlatch (the small, D-shaped plunger next to the long end of the main latch bolt) is not dropping into the frame cavity, the latch bolt will be held extended by the depressed deadlatch, thwarting shimming attacks.  Or does your latch not have a deadlatch? Photos of the latch bolt and striker cavity would help here as well...

Answer (score 1):

You can install a [cover plate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001LQW35M):

[image]

Obviously the screw heads have to be hard to open after installation.

Comment: +The cover plate is what is used on metal door frames and this stops a credit card from being used to open a locked door.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think about adding a shim piece between the door frame and the hinge plates. You'd be widening that gap but you'd be reducing the gap you're concerned with.